# How to mark a particular event date in Calander in IOS

Tags: ios

i am doing an application for IPhone in that i need to implement a calendar feature.I am usig calender which is really good and easy to use.now the problem is after an event is being added by the user i need to highlight that event date in the calendar.

please tell me what modifications that i need to do in the Library to achieve that.

all comments and answers are appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: Which library you are using?

Comment: When you say "highlight that event date in the calendar", are you talking about in the built-in Calendar app? Or are you showing it in your own UI?

Answer (score 0):

I have suggested this calendar..

https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSDayFlow